# Installing Quicklisp libraries in a Docker image

Tags: docker, common-lisp, gnu-common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp

Is there a Dockerfile for installing cl-json (or other Quicklisp library) on Docker? Most installation instructions I've seen require user input on commands with no --noinput flag, making it difficult to install through a Dockerfile.

In addition, many of the instructions appear out of date or reference broken links and non-existent resources. It would be convenient to use a Dockerfile to install it in a consistent way with e.g. Quicklisp.

Comment: Do you have an example of how other languages do this with docker?

Comment: Did you read http://margaine.com/2015/04/29/common-lisp-and-docker.html?

Comment: @coredump Sure thing: https://hub.docker.com/_/haskell/; florian margaine's article is good, but I don't see how to install a particular package in it.

Comment: `(or other json library)` you mean "other CL library" ?

Comment: Yes I do mean that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible Dockerfile for an application based on SBCL.

```
FROM dparnell/minimal-sbcl
RUN sbcl --noinform \
         --disable-ldb \
         --lose-on-corruption \
         --eval "(ql:quickload '(buildapp))" \
         --eval '(buildapp:build-buildapp "/bin/buildapp")'

RUN buildapp --load /opt/quicklisp/setup.lisp \
             --eval "(ql:quickload '(cl-json))" \
             --output bin/executable

CMD executable
```

I am basing the image on [dparnell/minimal-sbcl](https://github.com/dparnell/minimal-sbcl), which comes with Quicklisp pre-installed.

I then run SBCL once to build `buildapp` (that could be a separate docker image).

Then, I run `buildapp`, load `quicklisp/setup.lisp` and install `cl-json`. You can load as many dependencies you want with quickload, but I'd recommand defining your own `system.asd` file and list dependencies there.

Answer (score 1):

https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/testing.html#continuous-integration

In this tutorial we use Gitlab CI with the [daewok/lisp-devel](https://hub.docker.com/r/daewok/lisp-devel/) Docker image that includes several Lisp implementations and Quicklisp, so we can run a lisp and `(ql:quickload "cl-json")` right away.